# asp.net mvc download file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi Im having trouble downloading files using asp.net mvc y ycode is quite straight forward and seems to work for pdf's only. It does not work for other filetypes

the code is below and the mime types I use for the documents are below.

```
return File(doc.filepath, mime, doc.title);
```

1. Microsoft Word .doc application/msword
2. Adobe Acrobat .pdf application/pdf
3. Microsoft Powerpoint .ppt application/mspowerpoint
4. Microsoft Excel .xls application/x-excel
5. Text File .txt application/msword

Comment: "It does not work": could you give us more information ?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, nothing happens, no file dialog appears absolutely nothing, the same code works for pdf files though

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    FilePathResult result = new FilePathResult(doc.filepath, mime);
    result.FileDownloadName = doc.title
    return result;
```